# iis url redirect not working

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

Hey there my redicret is not working and i don't understand why.
My rule looks like this :

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rewrite to article" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^showfirm.asp\?rubrik=([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="esbjerg/sog/?q={R:1}&amp;t=" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

When i try to match the url with

```
http://localhost/showfirm.asp?rubrik=sometexthere
```

I hit my custom 404 page, instead of hitting

```
http://localhost/esbjerg/sog/?q=sometexthere&t=
```

Anyone who can help ? Im using an IIS 7.5 with urlrewriter 2.0

Ps : First time doing an url redirect :)

Comment: have you checked the order in which rules are defined?

Comment: Did you try escaping the dot in "showform.asp" ? I tried the regular expression in http://regexpal.com/ and without escaping it it didn't match the target sentence.

Comment: @furquan im not sure where I can check this, are you thinkin my web.config ? since i only have this rule there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<match url="^showfirm\.asp\?rubrik=([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
```

Comment: I just tried escaping it and it dosnt change anything, its true it should be escaped but when I test the pattern in iss urlrewriter it says its wrong with the \. :/